# Using Source Code Pro ExtraLight in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Source Code Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6J5l.png)

How to use ExtraLight in VSC ~?
It seems that the following is not working ...
I'm sure I have the fonts.

[Source Code Pro ExtraLight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKMRD.png)

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "source code pro",
"editor.fontWeight": "300",
```

Comment: "source code pro" worked instead of "Source Code Pro" in windows. Strange ! Thank you

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT: TL;DR** `editor.fontWeight` is back! `terminal.integrated.fontWeight` is there too!

`fontWeight` is not available in recent versions of VSCode, so Teo's suggestion doesn't work anymore.

Instead you can use the exact font file name (excluding full path and file extension):

```
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "SourceCodePro-Light"
}
```

Full list on my machine:

> /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-Light.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-BoldIt.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-Medium.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-SemiboldIt.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-Semibold.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-Bold.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-LightIt.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-ExtraLightIt.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-It.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-MediumIt.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-Black.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-BlackIt.otf
>   /Users/sebastian/Library/Fonts/SourceCodePro-ExtraLight.otf

Answer (score 1):

Tested on vscode 1.53.2

macOS:

```json
{
  "editor.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-ExtraLight'"
}
```

Windows:

```json
{
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Source Code Pro ExtraLight'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet for MacOS: Tested 6-Feb-2022 in VS Code.

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'SourceCodeRoman-ExtraLight'",
```